# Django postsave signal missing parameters when user logs in

Tags: python, django

This is my signal:

```
def deactivate_users_by_default(sender, user, created, **kwargs):
    print sender, user, created
    if created:
        user.is_active = False
        user.save()
signals.post_save.connect(deactivate_users_by_default, sender=User, dispatch_uid="deactivate_users_by_default")
```

When I login through the admin panel or the auth.login view I get this:

```
 response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
TypeError: deactivate_users_by_default() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Only looking at the error message: `user` is passed as `instance` keyword-only argument (in `**named`). Renaming `user` to `instance`should solve your problem.

Comment: @dhke ahh so the param name matters in this case? Thanks seems like that did the trick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a little bit hidden [in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/signals/#receiver-functions), but only the `sender` is passed as a positional argument to signal receivers. All other arguments (and that includes the `instance` argument of model signals) are passed as keyword args:

> Notice that the function takes a sender argument, along with wildcard keyword arguments (`**kwargs`); all signal handlers must take these arguments.

The implicit assertion here is that **all** non-sender arguments to a signal handlers are passed as keyword arguments.

`user` does not match any keyword supplied to [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/signals/#post-save) and there isn't a positional argument passed by the receiver to match it, hence the error message.

Redeclaring `deactivate_users_by_default` as

```
def deactivate_users_by_default(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
```

fixes your problem.